# How to restart the location update when the app is killed by user?

Tags: ios, swift, location, core-location, terminate

I'm trying to get the user location even if the app is in the background.

The application have also always location permission.

It is working well the app is in the background, but when the user **kills the app** it doesn't work.

I'm using this **startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges** to get the location

```
locationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
locationManager?.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
```

But after the phone is restarted, even if app is not running, the location update works.
Only when the app is killed by user on the task, it doesn't work.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        Log.debug("Did Enter Background")
        self.locationManager?.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        self.locationManager           = CLLocationManager()
        self.locationManager?.delegate = self
        self.locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        self.locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager?.distanceFilter = 500
        self.locationManager?.activityType = CLActivityType.otherNavigation
        self.locationManager!.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        self.locationManager?.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        self.locationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
}
```

Comment: `didEnterBackground` is too late to start significant location updates.  You need to start it while the app is in the foreground.  BTW, all of that set up with distance filtering and accuracy and activity type is unnecessary if you are just using significant location change

Comment: of course, if the user doesn't want, they can disable the permission on the setting.

Comment: That is true, but also if they swipe up Apple assumes they wanted it to stop running, however, try starting significant location updates when your app is in the foreground, not the background. I understand that people are confused about swiping away apps and thinks that it is a good thing to do, rather than a way to actually use more battery in the long term, but it is what it is.  Blame Microsoft for conditioning people to constantly shut things down and restart programs

Comment: Yes, it is started on the <b>didFinishLaunchingWithOptions</b>

Comment: Then you don't need the code you have shown in `didEnterBackground` and you just have to live with the fact that if people kill your app it stops.

Comment: From the docs: "If your app is terminated, the delivery of new location events stops altogether."
`allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` is limited to "when suspended".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved this by using **allowDeferredLocationUpdates**

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        Log.debug("Will Terminate")
        
        self.locationManager?.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        self.locationManager?.allowDeferredLocationUpdates(untilTraveled: 5, timeout: 60000)
        self.locationManager?.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

}
```

Comment: Hi were you able to track the SignificantLocationChanges  when the app was killed or suspended or in background ??